# Using Multiple Matlab GUIDE Sliders to Adjust Curve Parameters

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, parameters, matlab-guide

I am using Matlab GUIDE to adjust multiple parameters in a single curve. I can get a single slider to adjust a single parameter with all other parameters fixed but I have not been able to figure out or find a way to grab values from multiple sliders to adjust a single curve. Here is my code so far:

```
% --- Executes on slider movement.
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of          slider
By = get(handles.slider1,'Value');
Cy = 1.9; 
Dy = 1; 
Ey = 0.97;
ay = -15*pi/180:0.01:15*pi/180;
%alpha = -15:1:15;
Fy = (Dy*sin(Cy*atan((By*ay) - Ey*((By*ay) - atan(By*ay)))));
plot(handles.axes1,ay,Fy)

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: slider controls usually have a light gray background.
if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'),     get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end
```

I also have the same code for a second slider and the code for axes. I am plotting Fy vs ay and I want to have sliders to adjust the parameters Cy, Dy, and Ey. I am using Matlab R2015a.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution in your case is to call `slider2` callback at the end of `slider1` callback and vice versa.

You need to verfify the callback function executes only once - avoid the situatiuon when functions call one ontehr indedentlly.
Simple way to do that is checking the value of hObject.string (name of triggered object)

A more elegant solution is to create another function, that both callback executes (more elegant but requires more changes to your code).

Example:

---

`slider1_Callback:`

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    By = ...
    %...
    plot ...

    %Verifiy slider1_Callback is not executed within slider2_Callback.
    if isequal(get(hObject, 'String'), 'slider1')
        slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles); %Execute slider2_Callback
    end
```

---

`slider2_Callback:`

```
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    %begin of slider2 callback code
    ... 
    ...
    ...
    %end of slider2 callback code

    %Verifiy slider2_Callback is not executed within slider1_Callback.
    if isequal(get(hObject, 'String'), 'slider2')
        slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles); %Execute slider1_Callback
    end
```

---

In order to verify my answer I used the following code sample:
Example using two pushbuttons (without using `GUIDE`).

Both buttons changes color when one is pressed.

```
%Create GUI with two buttons, without using GUIDE.
function TestNoGuide()

    %Create figure.    
    handles.fig = figure('position', [800 400 260 100]);

    handles.pushbutton1 = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'position',[10 20 100 40], 'string' , 'Button1');

    handles.pushbutton2 = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'position',[150 20 100 40], 'string' , 'Button2');

    set(handles.pushbutton1, 'callback', {@pushbutton1_Callback, handles});
    set(handles.pushbutton2, 'callback', {@pushbutton2_Callback, handles});
end

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    set(handles.pushbutton1, 'BackgroundColor', rand(1, 3));

    if isequal(get(hObject, 'String'), 'Button1')
        pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles);
    end
end


function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    set(handles.pushbutton2, 'BackgroundColor', rand(1, 3));

    if isequal(get(hObject, 'String'), 'Button2')
        pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles);
    end
end
```

[image]

---

Demonstrating the more elegant solution:

```
function TestNoGuide()
    handles.fig = figure('position', [800 400 260 100]);
    handles.pushbutton1 = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'position',[10 20 100 40], 'string' , 'Button1');
    handles.pushbutton2 = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'position',[150 20 100 40], 'string' , 'Button2');
    set(handles.pushbutton1, 'callback', {@pushbutton1_Callback, handles});
    set(handles.pushbutton2, 'callback', {@pushbutton2_Callback, handles});
end

%Function is called form both callbacks
function ModifyBothButtons(handles)
    set(handles.pushbutton2, 'BackgroundColor', rand(1, 3));
    set(handles.pushbutton1, 'BackgroundColor', rand(1, 3));
end

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    ModifyBothButtons(handles);
end

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    ModifyBothButtons(handles);
end
```